# Restarting a wordpress project

Tags: wordpress

I am a freelance developer, and I normally build sites from scratch without using any code generating sites like WordPress or Square Space. But my current client insists on using WordPress. However, I am rescuing this project from a previous developer who made a big mess because from the looks of it does not seem like they knew what they were doing.

Is there a way for me to restart everything, on a clean slate and template on WordPress? I would like to have none of what the previous developer has done. Also is there a way for me do do direct coding using HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc on a WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to look into how to create a theme, since themes are the basis of the Wordpress structure. Ultimately, if you have the code for a website, it can be broken into separate files that Wordpress can use.

See: http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-theme-html-1/

Answer (score 0):

If the previous developer has done all the work in the theme files, then simply switching the theme to a default theme (Like Twenty Sixteen) will give you a nice clean slate to dig in and jump off with. You will want to create a child theme of any existing theme if you want to make any changes. If, however, the developer has messed with other files besides the theme folder, then you will most likely want to export the content only (as a logged-in administrator, go to Tools > Export [(here's a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sPo4.png))

Then on a new environment (I prefer testing these things first on a local virtual environment like VVV, and then transition to a development subdomain on the same server that the site will eventually go live on and securing it with an htaccess user/password to block curious eyes), import the content on a fresh installation of wordpress via the same menu (Tools > Import). This will give you a fresh installation with the content that's been created, but without any of the mess.

For more information about importing content - [here's the codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#WordPress).

I hope that's a good start - but if I've glossed over anything you don't understand, let me know - I'm happy to help.